# Python safe queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Is it save if I just using `put` and `get_nowait` functions in a queue, where the queue is shared between the threads. When Do I need to use a `thread lock`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essential idea of queue is to share it between multiple threads.
The Queue class implements all the required locking semantics. 
So you don't have to acquire lock explicitly.

http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#module-Queue

Answer (score 2):

The [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) module (called `queue` in Python 3) is specifically designed to work in multithreaded environments.

If that's what you're using, you don't need any additional locking.